# WordPress modifies my DOM structure?

Tags: html, wordpress, dom

I made a WordPress plugin that creates a shortcode that returns this string:

```
<span class="video-link-box">
    <a class="video-link" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$videoid}">{$content}</a>
    <div class="video-box video-box-hidden">
        <a class="video-box-exit" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
        <iframe width="{$width}" height="{$height}" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$videoid}?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <aside>{$caption}</aside>
    </div>
</span>
```

However, below is how Google chrome says it is being rendered. This worked before I made it into a WordPress plugin (static HTML, JS, and CSS). WordPress causes my JavaScript and stylesheets to partially fail. What is happening and how can I prevent this?

[image: Screenshot of Google Chrome]

EDIT: WordPress is intrusively adding `p` tags still. The above screenshot no longer reflects how the XHTML is being rendered but how can I prevent WordPress from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off the Wordpress auto-formatting, using [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) (or better by disabling that filter). There is also a plugin to turn off the auto-formatting on a per-post basis.

> Ah, and I forgot that WordPress doesn't use HTML5 too. Looks like I'll need to change `<aside>`

No, you don't need to, latest versions of [Wordpress know about the HTML5-tags](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L156). But as mentioned in the other answer, the wpautop-function also checks for correct block-element-nesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, people rely on WordPress autoformatting and if I disable it, the post (or site depending on which method I would hypothetically use) will look awry (but the plugin would work!). Is there a way to disable autoformatting for just a portion of a post?

Comment: @Tyler Crompton I think there was a plugin for such a purpose – something along "raw PHP/HTML", but I don't remember now.

Comment: I found it and am looking into it. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I should have clarified that my theme doesn't use HTML5.

Comment: How is the theme related to what you input into a post via the WP-editor in the backend? What do you mean by: "my theme doesn't use HTML5"? Are the appropriate tags simply not styled as they should be or didn't they show up at all (maybe because you're using MS IE, without a [HTML5-enabling-script](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/))?

Comment: DOCTYPE. It's using XHTML 1.0 Transitional, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

A `<span>` tag can never contain a `<div>`. Because the `<span>` is an inline element used for formatting inside of blocks like `<div>` or `<p>` tags. Inline elements can never contain block elements and Chrome is trying to normalize the invalid markup you gave it.

To solve the issue you should make the `video-link-box` a div. Maybe you need to apply some additional formatting.

Comment: The link to the video needs to be inline. So even if I change the `video-link-box`, I will still need to change the display to `inline`.

Comment: The CSS formatting is different from the definition of the markup language. The HTML specification strictly defines which tags can be contained inside which other tags. How you make them look and behave with CSS is a totally different issue and doesn't change the requirements of tag nesting defined in the HTML spec.

Comment: Ah, and I forgot that WordPress doesn't use HTML5 too. Looks like I'll need to change `<aside>` Now there is a line-break before the `video-box` but not after. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Now WordPress is still adding those `p` tags. That's what's causing the line breaks. Hmm.